# python + selenium: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I found the answer to this question in one of the post which worked for me in the following case:

```
<input class="some_class" value="test message">

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
            var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
            elm.value += txt;
            elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            """

message = ""
message_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, message_box, message)
message_box.send_keys(' ')
message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

but now I encountered different input style and above macro works no longer. When the message box is empty I can see the first statement. When I start to type to message box, "br" will change to "span"

```
1) <span data-offset-key="some_key">
       <br data-text="true">
2) <span data-offset-key="some_key">
       <span data-text="true">test message</span>
```

message_box.send_keys('non-wide character message') works when applied to `<span data-offset-key="some_key">`, macro does not work neither when applied to `<span data-offset-key="some_key">` nor `<span data-text="true">`. Any suggestions ? Thank you!